# Need Eclipse Galileo link for Flash Builder

Tags: eclipse, apache-flex, flex4, eclipselink, flash-builder

I have a Flash Builder 4 and i want to add Eclipse Galileo using install new software option.
I can able to find the link for Eclipse Ganymede but i could not find for Eclipse Galileo.
Please help me out how to add it.

Regards,
Ravi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Galileo is 4 years old.  I advise you reconsider its use.  Its update site is http://download.eclipse.org/releases/galileo/ .